# Singular support of a tempered distribution is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am reading *Introduction to the Theory of Distributions* by Friedlander and Joshi. As definition 8.6.1, they define the singular support of a tempered distribution $u$ to be the complement of {$x$: $u$ is $C^{\infty}$ on some neighborhood of $x$}.

From this definition I cannot see why the singular support of a tempered distribution need to be compact. But in proof for Lemma 8.6.1, they begin by choosing a test function $\phi$ such that $\phi\equiv 1$ on the singular support of a given tempered distribution.

Are they assuming that the singular support of a tempered distribution is compact? How can they do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can't. And it is probably a mistake in the book. The analogous statement in Hormander's *Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators* volume 1 is Theorem 4.2.5, where instead of $\mathscr{S}'$ the statement is given in terms of $\mathscr{E}'$, the space of distributions with compact support.

---

The [triangle-wave function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) gives an easy counterexample.

---

BTW, if you look at two pages on where the Lemma 8.6.1 is used, it is applied to $E * P\psi u$ where $E\in \mathscr{S}'$, $P$ is a linear partial differential operator,  $u\in \mathscr{D}'$, but $\psi$ is a smooth cutoff function. So necessarily $P\psi u\in \mathscr{E}'$.